# Why printf is not working in CUDA?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I refer the [link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#formatted-output) which says that if your device has compute capability greater than 2.0 then you can use printf() function in the CUDA kernel. When I tried the same I get the error **"calling a **host** function("printf") from a **global** function("mat_mul") is not allowed"**, but when I run same code on eclipse nsight I get the expected output and printf() function get executed. Why such different behaviour for nsight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you refer to:

> "calling a host function("printf") from a global function("mat_mul") is not allowed"

arises from *compiling* the code, not running the code.

So the difference lies in how your are compiling from "nvcc in terminal" vs. how it is set up to compile in nsight.

If you compile in the terminal with the additional architecture switch:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 ...
```

the error should go away.